# remove script actions on mobile size screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have the following script in my wordpress header which animates my #s-nav when the user scrolls up and not down (except for the first time)

However I don't want it to do it on mobile ( I want to be able to change the css when the screen is < 768px)

```
<script>
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

  setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
      hasScrolled();
      didScroll = false;
    }
  }, 250);

  function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
      // Scroll Down
      $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
      // Scroll Up
      if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
</script>
```

html

```
<nav id="s-nav" class="row nav-down">
    ...
</nav>
```

css

```
#s-nav { position: fixed; }
```

This doesn't seem to be the cleanest or easiest code to use, but it works. But it works on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `$( window ).width()` is the better option

```
function hasScrolled() {
 if($( window ).width() > 768){

   //do what ever you want to do

  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's me but when I add that to my code it does not work.  I wrapped my code in the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

To change the CSS based on viewport size, you can use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-up {
    /* empty */
  }
  .nav-down {
    /* empty */
  }
}
```

This would remove the styles for these classes when the viewport is less than 768px, which should prevent the animations.

Comment: I also want to remove the functionality ( the animating done by the script)

Comment: Don't the animations occur because of the CSS classes? Regardless, for your situation, it's probably best to use Syam's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a simple check like this one:

```
<?php

 if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {

?>

   <script>YOUR SCRIPT HERE OR JUST LOAD THE JS FILE</script>

<?php

 }

?>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: does this work only for mobiles, or does it work when the screen shrinks. Like is it detecting if its a phone or if the screen size is a certain size

Comment: This one works only for mobile. In order do make a responsive navigation you have to use CSS media queries